# How to find $dA$ for change of variables.

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus

If I want to compute the area element for a coordinate trasformation, let's say cartesian to polar
\begin{align*}
x &= r \cos \vartheta \\
y &= r \sin \vartheta
\end{align*}
to find $d A$ in the new coordinates I have to do
\begin{equation*}
d A = d x dy = |J|d r d\vartheta = r d r d\vartheta
\end{equation*}
But I asked myself, suppose I didn't know better, what would I do? Of course, instead of looking at the area element in the new coordinates, I would blindly compute
\begin{align*}
d x &= \cos \vartheta d r - r \sin \vartheta d\vartheta   \\
d y &= \sin \vartheta d r + r  \cos \vartheta d\vartheta
\end{align*}
and I would conclude (neglecting quadratic terms in $dr$ and $d\vartheta$) that
\begin{equation*}
d x d y = r \cos^2\vartheta d r d\vartheta -  r \sin^2\vartheta d\vartheta d r 
\end{equation*}
which is wrong. Considering $d x d y$ as an exterior product among forms I could still save the day because $dr d\vartheta = -d\vartheta d r$ but remaining in the "realm" of calculus 1 I am a bit lost. Why is this method not working?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actually, it involves cross product instead:

\begin{align*}
  \mathbf{r} &= \mathbf{r}(u,v) \\
  dA &=
  \left|
   \frac{\partial \mathbf{r}}{\partial u} \times
   \frac{\partial \mathbf{r}}{\partial v}
  \right| \, du \, dv
\end{align*}

which holds for surface too.

Comment: Are those 2d-vectors? I get the meaning though, the cross product gives me the area of the small parallelogram and that is the way to go.

Comment: You can always append an extra coordinate.  It's a usual trick to find an area of a parallelogram spanned by vectors $\mathbf{a}$ and $\mathbf{b}$: $$A=|\mathbf{a} \times \mathbf{b}|$$  By the way, we can also denote angular velocity by using curl: $$\boldsymbol{\omega}=\frac{1}{2} \nabla \times \mathbf{r}$$

Answer (score 1):

In general, for 3-dimensional curvilinear co-ordinates $u_i=\mathrm{constant}$, $i=1,2,3$ ; (it can be extended to n-dimensions), we can express any vector $\vec C$ as $$\vec C=h_1 \hat e_1+h_2 \hat e_2+h_3 \hat e_3$$ where $\hat e_i$ is the $\mathrm{i}^{\mathrm{th}}$ unit vector along the co-ordinate curve $u_i=\mathrm{constant}$ and $h_i$ is the scale factor of the $\mathrm{i}^{\mathrm{th}}$ unit vector $\hat e_i$.

Now, for such co-ordinates, a line element $\vec {dl}$ of $\vec C$ $= h_1 du_1+h_2 du_2+h_3 du_3$

And an area element $\vec {dA}$ is defined as $\vec {dA}= h_1 h_2 h_3\cdot (du_1)( du_2)(du_3)$

For planar polar co-ordinates, $u_1=r$ and $u_2=\theta$; and $h_1=1$ and $h_2=r$.

Nothing as such for $u_3$ as here the dimension is $2$.

So, in this case, $\vec {dA}= 1 \cdot r\cdot (dr)( d\theta)=\mathrm{r \,dr \,d\theta}$

Your procedure is wrong, since the area element is not defined in that way. This is the actual definition.